# Can I apply fore visa in Nepal before current Indian visa expires?

Tags: india, tourist-visas, uk-citizens, visa-extensions

My son, a UK citizen, is currently in India and wishes to stay longer.

Can he leave India and apply for another tourist visa from Nepal whilst his current visa is still valid?